# Can print graphics, but no text to Canon printer

Tags: pages, font, printing, text

This has stumped me. Printing was working normally before.

I wrote a document in Pages with text, and one horizontal divider line. I printed it, and only the line printed. After that point, I could only print graphics to the printer, not text.

Printer is a Canon imageCLASS MF8080Cw over a network. Printing the same PDF document from Windows works.

I tried:

- Print to PDF, then print PDF. Only the line printed.
- Save to RTF and open in Textedit, then print. Line was not exported to RTF, printed a blank page. Also printed from Libre Office, blank page.
- In Pages, changed text colour and font. No change.
- Printed a text chat. Emojis and bubbles printed, no text.
- Did a screen capture and printed that from preview. Image printed fine.
- Rebooted and tried again. Removed printer from settings, re-added, and tried again. No change.
- Printed a printer test page from the Canon print queue. Graphics part printed fine, no text.
- Tried to print text from Keynote, no text printed.

This baffles me. It as if a bug in Pages just made fonts disappear somewhere before the document gets sent out the network. It seems like there should be some way to reset that, but I don't know enough to know where or how. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same difficulty with a Canon MF641cw. I would like to know if the remove-and-reinstall-driver trick worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I uninstalled and reinstalled the printer driver software, which fixed the problem.

Comment: Did that resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes it did, but I still don't know the cause.

Comment: The fact that the problem was resolved - even if the cause remains unknown - should be included in your answer. You can use the [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/411186/edit) button to add this info.

Comment: Ran into the same thing with my Canon printer out of the blue, tried validating fonts which did nothing.  This was the fix.